# Can't clear a Winforms-ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

This is a rather simply question - but it's defeated me so far.

I have two list boxes on my form.  When the user clicks an item in the first box, the second list box populates with related values.  However sometimes I later want to clear the second listbox so it appears empty again.

However, none of the following seems to work:

```
lbxQuantity.Items.Clear();
lbxQuantity.DataSource = null;
lbxQuantity.Text = "";
```

How do I completely clear the listbox of all values and just leave it blank?

The listbox is in a WinForms application ad I'd like to add a button that clears all listboxes on the form.

Comment: in which event do you clear the items? try in listbox - prerender  or page prerender

Comment: `check the page load event you not binding the data source with listbox there.if it is then check for postbacks`. if you are clearing the all item's then there is no need to set datasource to null.however these has to work.try to bind after clearing items.

Comment: @Madhav: It also could be a [Winforms-ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) because it's not clear from the question.

Comment: `lbxQuantity.Items.Clear();` should work. Please post more details of your code.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter yeah i m sorry.i only thought for asp.net

Comment: Look at the last line of his post, it says it's a WinForms application

Comment: @Hanno: That was [edited later](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9108706/2), also the Winforms tagged by myself.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on which method you're using to fill the `ListBox`.

- If you're manually adding the items by calling `listBox.Items.Add` you can clear it through `listBox.Items.Clear`.
- If you're populating it through the DataSource, DisplayMember, and ValueMember properties you can set `DataSource = null` and then call `listBox.Items.Clear` in the `DataSourceChanged` event handler when the DataSource is null. You can of course also do it right after the null assignment.

Another possibility for the behavior you're seeing could be that listbox is repopulated in your own code through some event as soon as you remove all items.

Comment: The page to which the link is revering, seems to not exists anymore.

Comment: I removed the link